# Converting a object type to a datetime type in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, etl

[image]

I can't understand why this error message.

In the file 'ocorrencia_cvs' the datetime in df.ocorrencia_dia is 'dd/mm/yyyy', but I know that this column is a object type. When I try to convert it, this message is shown. Can someone help me?

I tried to convert it using 'to_datetime()' too. This way:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('ocorrencia.csv', sep=',')

df['ocorrencia_dia'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ocorrencia_dia'], format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

In this case the above message disappears and another message is shown:
[image: Error message]

Comment: Try adding `dayfirst=True` to your `pd.read_csv` ?

Comment: Yes man, I tried this too. When I did it, the message disappears, but the column type has not changed. It remains a object type.

Comment: Can you copy the error message into the question, rather than using a screenshot? It makes it easier to search the error message.

Comment: I would like to thank you all for your help. I managed to solve the problem, which was actually in the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

parse_dates option does not align with the date format in your file (DD/MM/YYYY).

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) , you might want to specify dtype as object and then try parsing the date using [`pandas.to_datetime` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) instead

For to_datetime function to work, you need to specify the datetime format that matches the value that is stored in the column.

**EDIT 1**

```
import pandas


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pandas.read_csv('ocorrencia_dia.csv', sep=',', dtype=object)
    df["ocorrencia_dia"] = pandas.to_datetime(df["ocorrencia_dia"], format="%d/%m/%Y") 
    print(df)
```

Comment: I try using pandas.to_datetime too. The result is the same.

Comment: Like this: df['ocorrencia_dia'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ocorrencia_dia'])

Comment: Have you tried it with the "format" option? For example, suppose the value in column "B" is "03/04/2022" (DD/MM/YYYY), you can then specify the format like so df["B"] = pandas.to_datetime(df["B"], format="%d/%m/%Y")

Comment: Yes man, I tried it. (df['ocorrencia_dia'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ocorrencia_dia'], format="%d/%m/%Y")). Than this error message appears:

Comment: TypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in _to_datetime_with_format(arg, orig_arg, name, tz, fmt, exact, errors, infer_datetime_format)
    509         try:                                                                                                          
    510             values, tz = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
    511             dta = DatetimeArray(values, dtype=tz_to_dtype(tz))

Comment: Ok man, what does mean this 'A' : 10?

Comment: It was meant to be a test column. Anyway, try this.
df = pandas.read_csv('ocorrencia_dia.csv', sep=',', dtype=object)
df["ocorrencia_dia"] = pandas.to_datetime(df["ocorrencia_dia"], format="%d/%m/%Y")
print(df)

Comment: I try it today, but another error message is shown. I described it in the question above.

Comment: Please provide the file ocorrencia_dia.csv, so it is easy to help troubleshoot